# Words that mean 'future consequences'?

Tags: vocabulary, future

I am wondering if someone can help me find a single word that means something along the lines of "future consequences" or "the intentional result of our present actions", mostly in a beneficial tone.

As a sort of rough hypothetical example, I mean a situation where a current scientist uses data from a long-dead scientist to come up with a great, beneficial discovery. I feel this captures a sort of fateful, beneficial, almost-intentional consequence of this long-dead scientists work that "resulted from", "based off of" and "as a consequence of" don't really capture.

Hope this makes sense, thanks.

Comment: Are you asking for a word that only applies to consequences that have not yet happened, as opposed to consequences that have already happened?

Comment: By "intentional result", do you mean that the original (now dead) scientist specifically *anticipated and intended* that his work should form the basis for a future discovery? In which case that future advance could be described as the *fulfillment, culminaton, fruition* of the earlier work.

Comment: Unclear.  *Future consequences* are not necessarily *intentional*. And your example doesn't correspond to either.

Comment: You need to clarify. Is the word to describe the situation? The current scientist? The long dead one? Give a sentence with a black where you think the word (or phase) would fit.

Answer (score 1):

The "fruits" of their work/ labor; to bring a plan to fruition.

Comment: Fruits of his/her life's work finally began to ripe....

Comment: The scientist's research finally bore fruit; the equation that he had worked so hard to uncover now showed its head.

Comment: Fruition definitely captures what I was going for, thanks! (and to FumbleFingers above).

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps you are looking for ***repercussions***...

According to [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com):

> [***Repercussion***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/repercussion)
>
> noun
>
> 1) (often plural) a result or consequence, esp one that is somewhat removed from the action or event which precipitated it   ⇒ "the repercussions of the war are still keenly felt"

Answer (score 0):

Often used is the slightly informal **spin-off**:

> spinoff or spin-off  n.
>
> ...
>
> 3. Something derived from an earlier work

[American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spin-off)